# Combining multiple rows into one row and appending the columns depending on the number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to combine multiple rows of same table into one.

I have a sample table like this

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
1   BH1 CB  12  CC  CC - Conveyor Mal.
1   BH1 CB  104 ZC  ZC - Full/Emp Signal Mal.
1   BH1 CB  109 HD  HD - Dosing Pipe Blocked
2   BH2 CD  14  HP  HP- Laptop
2   BH2 CD  21  DE  DE -Dell
3   BH1 BC  41  FE  FE- Fuji
4   BH9 BC  95  SN  SN-Sony
```

My expected out put should be some thing like this

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9    Col10   Col11   Col12
1   BH1 CB  12  CC  CC - Conveyor Mal.  104 ZC  ZC - Full/Emp Signal Mal.   109 HD  HD - Dosing Pipe Blocked
2   BH2 CD  14  HP  HP- Laptop  21  DE  DE -Dell             
3   BH1 BC  41  FE  FE- Fuji                         
4   BH9 BC  95  SN  SN-Sony
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is pretty obvious that the task cannot be fullfilled when there are more than 3 records belonging together, so please clarify. And what are the exact rules which rows should be grouped - is the first column the primary key? Or the first three together? And in which programming language do you want a solution - SQL only may be possible, but gives you not necessarily the most maintenance-friendly solution.

Comment: Hi Doc, First three columns are the primary key. I would require it in for sql server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use option with dynamicSQL, [APPLY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operators. In this scenario columns order in results, sorted by a column Col4.

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max),
        @query nvarchar(max)
SELECT @cols = 
  STUFF((SELECT x.ColName
         FROM (
               SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME('Col' + CAST(3 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Col3 ORDER BY Col4) AS nvarchar(10))) AS ColName,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Col3 ORDER BY Col4) AS rn
               FROM dbo.test31 CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Col'), ('Col'), ('Col')) o(Col)) x
         GROUP BY x.ColName, x.rn
         ORDER BY x.rn                   
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
SET @query = 
  'SELECT * FROM 
    (      
     SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3,            
            ''Col'' + CAST(3 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3 ORDER BY t.Col4) AS nvarchar(10)) AS ColName,            
            COALESCE(CAST(o.oCol4 AS nvarchar(10)), o.oCol5, o.oCol6) AS ListValues            
     FROM dbo.test31 t CROSS APPLY (
                                    SELECT oCol4, oCol5, oCol6
                                    FROM (VALUES (t.Col4, NULL, NULL),
                                                 (NULL, t.Col5, NULL),
                                                 (NULL, NULL, t.Col6))
                                    x(oCol4, oCol5, oCol6)
                                    ) o
     ) x
     PIVOT
      (
       MAX(ListValues) FOR ColName IN(' + @cols + ')
       ) p'
EXEC (@query)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5c2b/1)

Option with columns name like this " Plant, Brand, Area1,DownTime1,Reasons1,Area2,DownTime2,Reasons2 and so on."

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max),
        @query nvarchar(max)
SELECT @cols = 
  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(o.Col) AS ColName                
         FROM
          (
           SELECT *, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Plant, Brand ORDER BY Area) AS nvarchar(10)) AS rn
           FROM dbo.test35) t CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Area' + t.rn), ('DownTime' + t.rn), ('Reasons' + t.rn)
           ) o(Col)
         GROUP BY o.Col, t.rn
         ORDER BY t.rn                   
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')       

SET @query = 
  'SELECT * FROM 
    (      
     SELECT t.Plant, t.Brand, o.ColName,            
            COALESCE(CAST(o.Area AS nvarchar(10)), o.DownTime, o.Reasons) AS ListValues
     FROM
      (
       SELECT Plant, Brand, Area, DownTime, Reasons,
              CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Plant, Brand ORDER BY Area) AS nvarchar(10)) AS rn            
       FROM dbo.test35) t CROSS APPLY (
                                      SELECT Area, DownTime, Reasons, ColName
                                      FROM (VALUES (t.Area, NULL, NULL, ''Area'' + t.rn),
                                                   (NULL, t.DownTime, NULL, ''DownTime'' + t.rn),
                                                   (NULL, NULL, t.Reasons, ''Reasons'' + t.rn))
                                      x(Area, DownTime, Reasons, ColName)
                                      ) o
      ) x
     PIVOT
      (
       MAX(ListValues) FOR ColName IN(' + @cols + ')
       ) p'
EXEC (@query)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43a3c/1)

Comment: Hi  Alexander, Its been the answer i was looking for. Really appreciated. Thanks once again. Only one question is it possible to repeat the column names ? like say for example I have 5 columns "Plant, Brand, Area,DownTime,Reasons" now here Plant and Brand are the parent key. Is it possible to get the columns name like this " Plant, Brand, Area1,DownTime1,Reasons1,Area2,DownTime2,Reasons2 and so on.

Comment: Hi Alexander thanks a lot. it was the answer i was looking for. Perfect!!