# Can anyone write query for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, unpivot

My table is as below

```
recordId    fwildcardId refNumber   wildcardName    wildcardValue   comments
404450  154834               2              aaa               p          p
404450  154833               1              aa                oi         p   
406115  154867               1              98                ff        ff
406199  154869               1              aa                aaaa      ssss
406212  154880               1              bbbbb             card      comm
```

and I need the output as

```
      RecordId fwildcardid1 refNo1  Name1  Value1 comments1 fwildcardid2 refNo2 Name2 Value2 comments2 fwildcardid3 refNo3 Name3 Value3 comments3 
         404450  154834         2     aaa     p      p        154833       1     aa    oi        p 
         406115   Null         Null   Null   Null   Null      Null        Null   Null   Null   Null   154867        1     98       ff       ff
         406199   Null         Null   Null   Null    Null    154869       1      aa    aaaa     ssss      Null      Null     Null    Null
```

I tried pivoting like below , but didnt succeed .

```
select t1.recordId,t1.wildcardid as fwildcardId,t1.refNo as refNumber,t2.wildcardName,t1.attributeValue as wildcardValue,t1.comments 
into #tempp
from fwildcards t1
inner join fwildcardattributes t2 on t2.WildcardID=t1.attributenameid and t2.MarketID=5
inner join fitems t3 on t3.recordid=t1.recordid and t3.marketid=5
order by recordid,attributenameid


select * from #tempp
pivot (min (wildcardValue) for wildcardName in ([aaa],[aa],[aaaa],[98],[kki],[bbbbb],[SUN])) as wildcardValuePivot
```

Comment: is there any limit on repetition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining multiple rows into one row and appending the columns depending on the number of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355100/combining-multiple-rows-into-one-row-and-appending-the-columns-depending-on-the)

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh Have a look at my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Pivot Columns in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797691/dynamic-pivot-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this result, you will have to UNPIVOT and hen PIVOT the data.  The UNPIVOT will take the values in the columns `fwildcardId`, `refNumber`, `wildcardName`, `wildcardValue` and `comments` and turns them into rows.  Once the data is in rows, then you can apply the PIVOT function to get the final result.

To unpivot the data, you can use either the UNPIVOT function or you can use the CROSS APPLY and VALUES clause.

**UNPIVOT**:

```
select recordid,
  col+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
  unpiv_value
from
(
  select recordid,
    cast(fwildcardid as varchar(10)) fwildcardid,
    cast(refnumber as varchar(10)) refnumber,
    cast(wildcardname as varchar(10)) name,
    cast(wildcardvalue as varchar(10)) value,
    cast(comments as varchar(10)) comments,
    row_number() over(partition by recordid
                      order by fwildcardid) rn
  from tempp
) d
unpivot
(
  unpiv_value
  for col in (fwildcardid, refnumber, name, value, comments)
) c
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56180/25).

**CROSS APPLY and VALUES:**

```
select recordid,
  col+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
  value
from
(
  select recordid,
    cast(fwildcardid as varchar(10)) fwildcardid,
    cast(refnumber as varchar(10)) refnumber,
    wildcardname,
    wildcardvalue,
    comments,
    row_number() over(partition by recordid
                      order by fwildcardid) rn
  from tempp
) d
cross apply
(
  values
    ('fwildcardid', fwildcardid),
    ('refnumber', refnumber),
    ('name', wildcardname),
    ('value', wildcardvalue),
    ('comments', comments)
) c (col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56180/26).

These convert the results in a format:

```
| RECORDID |          COL |  VALUE |
------------------------------------
|   404450 | fwildcardid1 | 154833 |
|   404450 |   refnumber1 |      1 |
|   404450 |        name1 |     aa |
|   404450 |       value1 |     oi |
|   404450 |    comments1 |      p |
|   404450 | fwildcardid2 | 154834 |
```

When you unpivot data into the same column, it has to be the same datatype.  You will notice that I applied a `cast` to the columns so the datatype is the same.

Once the data is in the row format, you can convert it back into columns with PIVOT:

```
select *
from
(
  select recordid,
    col+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
    unpiv_value
  from
  (
    select recordid,
      cast(fwildcardid as varchar(10)) fwildcardid,
      cast(refnumber as varchar(10)) refnumber,
      cast(wildcardname as varchar(10)) name,
      cast(wildcardvalue as varchar(10)) value,
      cast(comments as varchar(10)) comments,
      row_number() over(partition by recordid
                        order by fwildcardid) rn
    from tempp
  ) d
  unpivot
  (
    unpiv_value
    for col in (fwildcardid, refnumber, name, value, comments)
  ) c 
) src
pivot
(
  max(unpiv_value)
  for col in (fwildcardid1, refnumber1, name1, value1, comments1,
              fwildcardid2, refnumber2, name2, value2, comments2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56180/13).

The above version works great if you have a known number of columns, but if you will have an unknown number of values that will be converted into columns, then you will need to use dynamic sql to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(c.col+cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by recordid
                                                order by fwildcardid) rn
                      from tempp
                    ) t
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'fwildcardid' col, 1 sortorder union all
                      select 'refNumber', 2 union all
                      select 'name', 3 union all
                      select 'value', 4 union all
                      select 'comments', 5
                    ) c 
                    group by col, rn, sortorder
                    order by rn, sortorder
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT recordid,' + @cols + ' from 
            (
              select recordid,
                col+cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
                unpiv_value
              from
              (
                select recordid,
                  cast(fwildcardid as varchar(10)) fwildcardid,
                  cast(refnumber as varchar(10)) refnumber,
                  cast(wildcardname as varchar(10)) name,
                  cast(wildcardvalue as varchar(10)) value,
                  cast(comments as varchar(10)) comments,
                  row_number() over(partition by recordid
                                    order by fwildcardid) rn
                from tempp
              ) d
              unpivot
              (
                unpiv_value
                for col in (fwildcardid, refnumber, name, value, comments)
              ) c 
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                max(unpiv_value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56180/24). Both of these give the result:

```
| RECORDID | FWILDCARDID1 | REFNUMBER1 | NAME1 | VALUE1 | COMMENTS1 | FWILDCARDID2 | REFNUMBER2 |  NAME2 | VALUE2 | COMMENTS2 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   404450 |       154833 |          1 |    aa |     oi |         p |       154834 |          2 |    aaa |      p |         p |
|   406115 |       154867 |          1 |    98 |     ff |        ff |       (null) |     (null) | (null) | (null) |    (null) |
|   406199 |       154869 |          1 |   kki |   aaaa |      ssss |       (null) |     (null) | (null) | (null) |    (null) |
|   406212 |       154880 |          1 | bbbbb |   card |      comm |       (null) |     (null) | (null) | (null) |    (null) |
```

Comment: I achieved this by other means also . but prob with this approach is that it will have different name1 values for different records . my requirement is aa should be always name1 , 98 should be always name 2 , kki should be always name 3 so on . if records doesnt have wild cardswith name as aa for those name1 should be null similarly other fields with 1 also null as the record is not having a wildcard with aa.

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh Please edit your OP with the full requirements for your question.

Comment: I updated the output . see there Name2 is always "aa" . If the records not having names with "aa" entrire series of columns with suffix 2 should be null

Answer (score 0):

**No Pivot No Cross Apply**

According to **edited** Question.

```
select 
DISTINCT
A.recordId AS recordId,
A1.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId1,
A1.refNumber AS refNumber1,
A1.wildcardName AS wildcardName1,
A1.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue1,
A1.comments AS comments1,
A2.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId2,
A2.refNumber AS refNumber2,
A2.wildcardName AS wildcardName2,
A2.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue2,
A2.comments AS comments2,
A3.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId3,
A3.refNumber AS refNumber3,
A3.wildcardName AS wildcardName3,
A3.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue3,
A3.comments AS comments3,
A4.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId4,
A4.refNumber AS refNumber4,
A4.wildcardName AS wildcardName4,
A4.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue4,
A4.comments AS comments4,
A5.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId5,
A5.refNumber AS refNumber5,
A5.wildcardName AS wildcardName5,
A5.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue5,
A5.comments AS comments5,
A6.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId6,
A6.refNumber AS refNumber6,
A6.wildcardName AS wildcardName6,
A6.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue6,
A6.comments AS comments6,
A7.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId7,
A7.refNumber AS refNumber7,
A7.wildcardName AS wildcardName7,
A7.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue7,
A7.comments AS comments7,
A8.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId8,
A8.refNumber AS refNumber8,
A8.wildcardName AS wildcardName8,
A8.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue8,
A8.comments AS comments8,
A9.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId9,
A9.refNumber AS refNumber9,
A9.wildcardName AS wildcardName9,
A9.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue9,
A9.comments AS comments9,
A10.fwildcardId AS fwildcardId10,
A10.refNumber AS refNumber10,
A10.wildcardName AS wildcardName10,
A10.wildcardValue AS wildcardValue10,
A10.comments AS comments10
from Table_name A
LEFt JOIN Table_name A1 ON A.recordId=A1.recordId AND A1.wildcardName='aaa'
LEFT JOIN Table_name A2 ON A.recordId=A2.recordId AND A2.wildcardName='aa'
LEFT JOIN Table_name A3 ON A.recordId=A3.recordId AND A3.wildcardName='98'
LEFT JOIN Table_name A4 ON A.recordId=A4.recordId AND A4.wildcardName=''
LEFT JOIN Table_name A5 ON A.recordId=A5.recordId AND A5.wildcardName=''
LEFT JOIN Table_name A6 ON A.recordId=A6.recordId AND A6.wildcardName=''
LEFT JOIN Table_name A7 ON A.recordId=A7.recordId AND A7.wildcardName=''
LEFT JOIN Table_name A8 ON A.recordId=A8.recordId AND A8.wildcardName=''
LEFT JOIN Table_name A9 ON A.recordId=A9.recordId AND A9.wildcardName=''
LEFT JOIN Table_name A10 ON A.recordId=A10.recordId AND A10.wildcardName=''
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/daf69/1)**

Comment: no this query also doesnt keep wildcard names in fixed position

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh Gottcha. Just give me time, I will be able to give answer.

Comment: No problem . i will be trying till den !

Comment: Also please provide what should be the **name** for **4,5,6,7,8,9,10**

Comment: Difficult to write everything . But I will make it clear . Say max allowed names will be 10 . if the records are m,ore than 1000 also their names will be within this 10 wildcard names  . one record id can have more than one wildcards  . for all records particular wildcardname should be there in same position . a particular wildcard name acnnot repeat for a record . thats  record 400000 cannot have wildcard with name "aa" twice .

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh you are changing your requirement day by day. Please specify your requirement at once.

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh Does the Answer helped you. If yes you should try and Consider it as your answer,